# Guzzle Http 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I want to use [Guzzle Http](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) for calling an external API. I am using a bad structure for the `body` of the request in my code.

**This is the `json body` from the `postman` that WORKS JUST FINE:**

```
// json body that works fine on postman.
{
    "field_1": "aaa",
    "field_2": "bbb",
    "field_3": [
        {
            "field_a": "ccc",
            "field_b": "ddd",
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is the `equivalent code` I expect to work:**

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client   = new Client;
$response = $client->request('POST',
    "https://api.test.com/v1/some-endpoint",
    [
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer some-access-token',
        ],
        'json'    => [
            'field_1' => "aaa",
            'field_2' => "bbb",
            'field_3' => [
                'field_a' => "ccc",
                'field_b' => "ddd",
            ],
        ],
    ]
);
```

This leads to this error:

```
  Exception trace:

  1   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
      /var/www/my-project/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:65

  2   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
      /var/www/my-project/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php:203

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: Seems good, but docs say you shouldn't set header if use `json` type as params. Maybe it can help. Also, you have to make sure your guzzle version supports `json`, or use `body` instead

Comment: No, I am sure about the syntax that should be `headers` and `json` since I am using this syntax everyday on other places. The problem seems to be on the structure of the  `json` array.

Answer (score -2):

Replace

```
$client = new Client;
```

with

```
$client = new Client();
```